# SQL in SAS: Trying to count zero values by left-join

Tags: sql, sas, left-join

Despite thorough research on my issue, I was not yet able to solve my issue that I encountered with an SQL-query.

I have a two-dimensional query on a customer-database. I would like to sort all purchase amounts by customer and product. 
Since not all customers purchased every product, it is mandatory to also display the products with zero purchase from every customer.

I have two tables: The big table `purchases` with all single transactions and a second table `products`, that was generated by a simple query from the `purchases` database.

That table is used to list all possible products.

My query looks like the following:

```
proc sql; 
create table customers_products 
as select  a.customers as customers, b.products as product,sum(a.amount) as amount format=comma16.0, count(a.amount) as transactions format=comma16.0
from products as b 
left join work.transactions as a on b.product = a.product
group by a.customers , b.products 
order by a.products, amount desc; 
quit;
```

However, there are no zero-counts. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide sample data and desired output? BTW, it seems you have a typo in your second paragraph *"[...] by product and product."*. Also, you mention two tables, `products` and `purchases`, yet in your query there is `product` and `transactions`.

Comment: I corrected the typo to "purchase amounts by customer and product". That should be the correct description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler way to do this, but here is how I would tackle your problem

First: here is some sample purchases.  Each customer has a 60% chance of buying a product 1 or more times:

```
data purchases;
do customer=1 to 10;
    do product=1 to 10;
        if ranuni(1) > .4 then do;
            x = ceil(4*ranuni(1)); /*Buy 1 to 4 times*/
            do i=1 to x;
                amount = ranuni(1)*10;
                output;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
drop i x;
run;
```

Next, I get the distinct products and customers, and I get the totals for each customer/product group.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table products as
select distinct product from purchases;

create table customers as
select distinct customer from purchases;

create table totals as
select customer, product, sum(amount) as amt
from purchases
group by customer, product;
quit;
```

Your problem involves a Cartesian product on customers and products -- i.e. you want all customers and products.  So I go ahead and do that here.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table customers_x_products as 
select a.customer, b.product
from customers as a, 
     products as b;
quit;
```

Finally, I put that customers_x_products table with the totals table to produce the table I think you are looking for:

```
proc sql noprint;
create table customers_products as
select b.customer,
       b.product,
       coalesce(a.amt,0) as amt
    from customers_x_products as b
      left join
         totals as a
      on a.product=b.product 
      and a.customer=b.customer
    order by b.customer, b.product;
quit;
```

Comment: Yes, I think we are coming closer. Please see my comment to user2877959: I intended to get an output table like Customer X: product a=, product b=1, product c=0, product d=0; Customer Y: product a=0, product b=0, product c=5, product d=0

Comment: Do you want the count of times purchased or the sum of amount?  What I have is exactly what you describe with a sum on amount.  If you want a count of times purchased, change `sum()` to `count()` and you will have it.

Comment: Yes, I need both sum and count. But the output table that you provided is exactly what I need! I didn't expect it to be that complicated though by using the carthesian product. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your proplem?
Lacking sample data and desired output, I could not test it.

```
proc sql; 
create table customers_products as
select a.customers as customers
      ,b.products as product
      ,sum(a.amount) as amount format=comma16.0
      ,case
        when sum(a.amount) is missing then 0
        else count(a.amount) 
       end as transactions format=comma16.0
from products as b 
left join work.transactions as a on b.product = a.product
group by a.customers , b.products 
order by a.products, amount desc; 
quit;
```

EDIT: I see now that, in your query you have both a `product` and a `products` variable. Is that a typo?

EDIT 2: I made some sample data and ran your query on it

```
data products;
infile datalines;
input product $;
datalines;
a
b
c
d
;
run;
data transactions;
infile datalines;
input customers $ product $ amount;
datalines;
X a 3
X b 1
Y c 5
;
run;

proc sql; 
create table customers_products as
select a.customers as customers
            ,b.product as product
            ,sum(a.amount) as amount format=comma16.0
            ,count(a.amount) as transactions format=comma16.0
from products as b 
left join transactions as a on b.product = a.product
group by a.customers , b.product 
order by a.product, amount desc; 
quit;
```

This is your exact query except that I assumed your varying references to `prodcuts` and `product` were a mistake and I changed them all to `product`.
This produces the following result:

```
customers product amount transactions
-------------------------------------
          d       .      0
X         a       3      1
X         b       1      1
Y         c       5      1
```

As you can see, I get a record with zero-value count of transaction for product `b`. So I'm not sure I understand what your problem is (again stressing why it is really helpful if questions include sample data and desired output).

Comment: First, many thanks for your reply! You provided a corrected interpretation of my data-structure. However, what I intended to get was the following: Customer X: product a=, product b=1, product c=0, product d=0; Customer Y: product a=0, product b=0, product c=5, product d=0